# qt printer for embedded

Tags: qt, printing, embedded

I'm developing an embedded system using Buildroot on cubieboard2 hardware. my toolchain is an external linaro and Application programming language is Qt. I compiled the project successfully and every thing was fine. now I want to add printing support to the project, but there is some errors. the scenario is as follow:

1. I compiled CUPS using xconfig mechanism. but foomatic filters were
   not supported by Buildroot. So I added cups-filters package
   following bellow link:
   http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2015-March/123001.html
2. For my printer (hp 1102P), driver package (HPLIP) was included to
   the Buildroot so using xconfig mechanism I compiled this driver
   pack, but could not print and got filter error. so I googled the
   problem and found an open source driver (foozjs2) and solved this
   problem.
3. Printer classes in my application use `QPrinter` and `QPainter`.

My problem is simple! nothing works and there is no error! Anybody can help me?

Comment: Does not look like a programming question.

Comment: _my problem is simple!!!_ You didn't describe the problem nor post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)